# Kapp is not showing colors in gitlab-ci

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I started using kapp to manage the cluster, and I wanted to configure it with gitlab-ci and I came across one problem, there are no colors in the gitlab-ci terminal, while everything works fine locally.

Changing the `--color = "true"` flag does nothing. Anyone had a similar problem?

Here is an [example](https://gitlab.com/marek_m71/kapp), zero colors, while locally all changes are marked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been fixed in release v0.23.0 https://github.com/k14s/kapp/issues/84